# breaking out of a loop logic in Java

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm

I'm learning Java and just started playing around with mysql and am having a bit of a problem with some logic that worked in python and I'm having trouble converting.

I basically have a try statement that tries to search if a record exists in a database..If it does then great, it moves on but if the record does not exist then it added it.  Here's my code

```
try 
{
    PreparedStatement Findstatement;
    Findstatement = con.prepareStatement(" SELECT DataMaster_MasterCode FROM Allocation WHERE Master_Code = (?) and date = (?)");
    Findstatement.setInt(1, Code);
    Findstatement.setString(2, AllocationDate);
    ResultSet CodeAll  = Findstatement.executeQuery();
    int DataMaster_MasterCode;
    while (CodeAll.next()) 
    {
        DataMaster_MasterCode = CodeAll.getInt("DataMaster_MasterCode");
    }


    System.out.println("Found allocation "  + DataMaster_MasterCode + " already exists for " + Name);

}
catch (Exception e) 
{ //Create statements... }
```

The problem is it keeps going to the exception because the DataMaster_MasterCode variable may not be may not be initialized.  I think because python just executes the code as it goes along it works in python but because java precompiles it, it sees this as an error and skips.  If the variable is not may not be initialized I want it to fail and go to the catch statement(which creates the variable).

Right now it keeps failing and keeps creating(duplicating) entries because it never finishes the statement to find the data itself.  I thought about putting an else if statement that checks of the variable is null and then breaks but it didn't work for me either.

Please help me with the logic.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, since you are reading a variable (`DataMaster_MasterCode`) that may not have been initialized. What does your code *really* look like? Also, note that the Java convention is to begin local variable names with a lower case letter. Following the conventions makes it easier for experienced Java developers to understand your code and see the real problem, rather than stumbling over oddities that aren't really significant.

Comment: *"it keeps going to the exception because the DataMaster_MasterCode variable may not be may not be initialized"* ... No, it doesn't. That's not an exception.

Comment: That was my code..It wouldn't run the code I posted and would go directly to the catch section.  I changed the names of the variables to make them more easier for people here to understand what it was doing but other then that it was my code.  I'll fix my naming conversation, I just realized I was using my own style(I'll read up on proper naming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use exception handling only for exceptional cases. Checking for an uninitialized value is not one of them. To check for a null value in Java, simply use (variable == null).

Comment: ok I'll look more into trys statements..I basically needed it to try something and if it doesn't work then do something else..it could fail at any number of points so an if statement wasn't easy.  If I check for the null variable, it confirms its null but it doesn't like me break out of the try statement and into the catch statement.

Comment: You can't break into a catch block. You might create a method to handle errors and call it in the catch block as well as if you get a null value. It's also not wrong to catch exceptions that might be unexpected, i.e. when the logic fails, but as Zian already said, an unitialized variable is not among them. You should do your best to prevent expected exceptions or fix code errors (which an uninitialized variable is).

Comment: That's because `try` and `catch` statements are meant to handle exceptions -- which, by definition, are not normal occurrences.  They're meant for cases which shouldn't happen, not for flow control.  If you have a case that's common enough that you have code to check for it, then it's not an exceptional case (and try/catch shouldn't be used).

Comment: Thank you so much. I did get it to work.  I basically made the variable null and then had an if statement under it that added the data if the code was null.  It seems to work now(not adding duplicates).  Thank you so much and in addition to solving this problem I think I learned I was making much more serious mistakes in my use of try statements and naming.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You first have to assign null to the variables, otherwise you'd get an exception as well. Note that local variables are not initialized to any default, so do  `DataMaster_MasterCode = 0;` etc.